# Which php frameworks would be best to work with NoSQL database like Cassandra?

Tags: php, database, laravel, yii, nosql

Yii, Laravel, CI & Cakephp are best known php frameworks in market, I would like to know / confirm that does all these above frameworks works efficiently with NoSQL databases like Cassandra or Mongodb?

- I am not sure about it so can anyone help to me understand it briefly?
- Does server side validations can be performed if we go with NoSQL type database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sure that you can work with Mongo from all framework that you need.
Example from google:

- http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/?tag=mongodb
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html
- https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Select Framework that you like or have experience. Each of them have great community and solution work with NoSQL DB.

Regarding server side validation. Why not?
Server validation should not connected to selected DB.

Difference from MySQL that if you enter invalid data it show you error. In NoSQL that value accepted. But correct behavior work with DB it's validate information before it pass DB.
So first you validate POST then if it valid pass it to DB.